# HTML5 priority between playing and preloading video

Tags: html5-video

First time poster here, I'd like to know if there are any specifications about the priority, in HTML5, between a `<video>` which is already playing and another  that's preloading.

Let's say I have a `<video>` that's is currently playing. It's not entirely preloaded (and shouldn't be) so it's still loading as it is playing.
On top of that, sometime during this first video playback, I'm inserting via JS another `<video>`, and expectedly this video begins preloading.

What I would like to know is, of those two videos, which one as the priority on loading its content?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will find this is largely browser and platform dependent, but there are mechanisms, 'Priority Hints' and 'Resource Hints', which allow you tell the browser that a particular resource, e.g. video, image, script etc is lower or higher priority, or need to be preloaded etc.

More info here at the time of writing:

- https://www.w3.org/TR/resource-hints/ (w3 spec)
- https://wicg.github.io/priority-hints/ (unofficial Priority Hints draft spec)
- https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/priority-hints (a developers overview from Google)

Note that browser support differs for these features, especially Priority Hints which is new and may be only available in Chrome Beta releases, so it is worth checking support before deciding if you decode to use these mechanisms.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look!